# running spark-ec2 with --worker-instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

right an absolute spark noob is talking here.

this is the command I'm running and expecting 3 workers

```
./spark-ec2  --worker-instances=3 --key-pair=my.key --identity-file=mykey.pem --region=us-east-1 --zone=us-east-1a  launch my-spark-cluster-G
```

however, in `aws console` only two servers will be created (`master` and `slave`)

on the other side  in :

```
http://myMasterSparkURL:8080/
```

I get the following info which does not just add up:

```
Workers: 3
Cores: 3 Total, 3 Used
Memory: 18.8 GB Total, 18.0 GB Used
Applications: 1 Running, 0 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE
```

and under workers it shows:

```
worker1 (port 8081) worker1IP:43595 ALIVE   1 (1 Used)  6.3 GB (6.0 GB Used)
worker1 (port 8082) worker1IP:53195 ALIVE   1 (1 Used)  6.3 GB (6.0 GB Used)
worker1 (port 8083) worker1IP:41683 ALIVE   1 (1 Used)  6.3 GB (6.0 GB Used)
```

now if I click on the first one (`worker with 8081`) it redirected me to the worker page however if I click on the other two (`workers with port 8082 and 8083`). it basically says `page not found`.

with high probability I am assuming this is a bug in `spark-ec2` but I'm not quite sure since I'm a noob here.

I've searched all over the place to find someone with similar issue. so I appreciate any suggestion where can give me some ideas why this is happening and how to fix it. ty

The spark version `spark-1.3.0`

Comment: I haven't used the `--worker-instances` option before, but did you perhaps just mean instead to use the `--slaves` option?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change that invokation a little, this is how I have been creating clusters so far:

```
./spark-ec2 -k MyKey 
            -i MyKey.pem 
            -s 3 
            --instance-type=m3.medium 
            --region=eu-west-1 
            --spark-version=1.2.0 
            launch MyCluster
```